# Парсинг CSV на php, странная проблема

Tags: php, csv

Здравствуйте, есть файл csv, практически все строки парсятся нормально, разделителем выступает `|`, но есть некоторые строки, которые некорректно обрабатываются, я не могу понять почему, вот пример одной такой строки через `var_dump`

```
array(8) {
[0]=>
string(8) "02101011"
[1]=>
string(14) "24010170040А4"
[2]=>
string(10) "8421990000"
[3]=>
string(72) "Элемент фильт. масл. МАЗ 5205 (прво Цитрон)"
[4]=>
string(74) "Елемент фільт. масл. МАЗ 5205 (вирво Цитрон)"
[5]=>
string(52) "Цитрон Концерн, г.Михайловск"
[6]=>
string(608) "синтетич. нетканое полотно, пружинный каркасD = 100, d = 39, H = 200 МАЗ 54323, 53362, 64229 КрАЗ 260, 643071, 6443, 6503, 65055 БелАЗ 75405, 5405, 754007,75485, 75486, 75487, 7540, 7523, 7527, 752301  МоАЗ 6014, 6442, 7505 дв.ЯМЗ238, 240, 240Б погрузчики, катки ЭО5122, 5123|145,38|151,44|211,98|Штука|0|0,32000|100|200|100|{СписокЗначений",{{{"Строка","МАЗ"},"","0"},{{"Строка","КрАЗ"},"","0"},{{"Строка","Сельхозтехника"},"","0"},{{"Строка","БелАЗ"},"","0"}}}"
[7]=>
string(81) "{"СписокЗначений",{{{"Строка","Двигатель"},"","0"}}}"
}
```

проблема в шестом элементе массива, там присутствуют разделители, элемнтов массива всего должно быть 18, но почему-то именно там скрипт не видит этих разделителей.
Вот код самого скрипта:

```
$f = fopen('price.csv', 'r');
while(!feof($f)) {
    $data = fgetcsv($f, 10000, '|');
    var_dump($data);
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Файл в кодировке UTF8?

Comment: Да, но изначально он в Windows-1251 идет, я через нотпад меняю кодировку на UTF8

Comment: Как вариант: параметр `length
Должен быть больше самой длинной строки (в символах), найденной в CSV-файле (включая завершающий символ конца строки). В противном случае, строка будет разбита на куски длиной в length...

Опускание этого параметра (или установка его в 0 в PHP 5.1.0 и выше) приведет к тому, что длина строки будет неограничена. Это может сказаться на скорости выполнения.`

Я понимаю, что проблема вряд ли в этом (у Вас там явно нет 10К символов). Можете привести пример нормальной строки, которая парсится правильно?

Comment: лучше эту строку целиком представьте, а не дамп разбора, и допустим предыдущую, где все корректно